# Issue with Marquee

Tags: javascript, html, css

how can html stop marquee element using javascript as my wish ?

Let,

```
<marquee behavior="alternate" direction="right">hello</marquee>
```

I want to stop moving the text hello when I put mouse over it.

Thanks.

Comment: `<marquee onmouseover="this.stop();" onmouseout="this.start();" behavior="alternate" direction="right">hello</marquee>`

Comment: `<marquee>` has been deprecated has it not?

Answer (score 3):

You can simply add the behavior change inline:

```
<marquee behavior="alternate" onmouseover="this.scrollAmount = 0" 
onmouseout="this.scrollAmount=10" direction="right">hello</marquee>
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/3kedfyos/)

Answer (score 2):

demo - http://jsfiddle.net/h4ww3jsv/

```html
<marquee onmouseover="this.stop();" onmouseout="this.start();" behavior="alternate" direction="right">hello</marquee>
```

Answer (score 1):

Code below wont work on Mozilla v27

```
<marquee behavior="alternate" onmouseover="this.scrollAmount = 0" 
onmouseout="this.scrollAmount=10" direction="right">hello</marquee>
```

Solution to this problem is by using following code

```
<marquee onMouseOver="this.setAttribute('scrollamount', 0, 0);" OnMouseOut="this.setAttribute('scrollamount', 6, 0);">Hello</marquee>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3kedfyos/3/

I recommend also reading https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/marquee

Comment: For this reason i have attached the link from mozilla see what they have to say https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/marquee